# What is a safe distance for a barefoot running on asphalt?

Tags: injury, long-distance-running, running-shoes, barefoot, marathon

I mean not totally barefoot, I mean using VFF or something like Nike free run 3.0, in my long run I do a good 10-13k in barefoot, but after that my feets gets a lot of pain. I think my foots has been much stronger, and maybe it could be a good distance to run just 10k barefoot for maintaining stronger feets, and then to do long run with a cushioner shoe..

Edited:
My Body weight is 83k, and my height is 1.80, I think running barefoot could be maybe something for people that weights <= 70 Kg on long distances, but for heavier people we must do just 10k or use maybe a middle cushion shoe like Saucony Kinvara 3 that alows you to run like a forefoot strike runner but alows you to run heel-strike too.

Comment: I'm not sure that there's any answer to be given; depends too much on specifics about you and your conditioning for this type of running. I think you should just listen to your body: if/when it hurts, stop.

Comment: Your question looks to be very personal dependent. +1 for @Greg's comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran long distances for two years in minimalist shoes, and have just now realized that yes, minimalist shoes are great for improving your form and reducing injury, but they still mask just enough of your senses to make it harder to perfect your form—specifically, running efficiently with as little impact as possible. Also, minimalist shoes need to fit quite snugly to prevent blisters, so I can feel a lot of pressure on the tops and sides of my feet, even running on soft surfaces, late in a long run. I've been trying out true barefoot running recently with good results.

I would suggest visiting some barefoot running web sites or forums, or reading a book or two, to learn how to perfect your form. You may need to increase your cadence or work on a lighter foot landing. I think two of the most important tips for running more lightly are to bend your knees more than you think (meaning sink your hips down, not run with "high knees") and to focus on lifting your feet from the pavement rather than pushing off. When I count cadence while running, I count each step as the feet lift from the ground rather than counting as they touch the ground.

You ultimately will need to listen to your body, as mentioned by @Igaud.

Answer (score 3):

There's no universal cap on barefoot running. People do ultramarathons barefoot, and marathons that are entirely on asphalt. But pretty much any source on barefoot/minimalist running advice is going to tell you to ease into it to build up the strength in your feet. If doing more than 10k causes you pain, listen to your body and keep it to shorter runs for now.